# Cucumber Spring PageObjectModel

Tags: spring, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pageobjects

I'm trying to Integrate Spring into Cucumber Selenium Project.

Project is already configured with `PageObjectModel` design pattern and working perfectly before integrating with Spring.

```
public abstract class BasePage {

    public WebDriver driver;


    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void verifyPage() {
       //verify page
    }

}


public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "MENU_lINK")
    private Link MENU_HEADER;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
    }

    public Link getMENU_HEADER() {
        return MENU_HEADER;
    }
}



public class HomePageSteps {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HomePageSteps.class.getName());

    private WebDriver driver;
    HomePage homePage;
    HelperPage helperPage;

    public HomePageSteps() {
        driver  = WebDriverProvider.driver; //Driver initiated here
       homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }

    @Given("I'm on home page")
    public void navigateToHomePage() {
        homePage.getMENU_HEADER().click();
    }
```

After integrating with Spring issue noticed is all the features are executing in same browser.

Before Spring integration each feature used to execute in separated browser as  `@After` and `@Before` annotations are used that are available in Cucumber

```
public class WebDriverProvider {
    public static WebDriver driver;


    @Before
    public void openBrowser() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", new File(".").getAbsolutePath() + "/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        if (driver != null) driver.quit();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    @After
    public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

After integration with Spring in `applicationcontext.xml` file I have defined the Driver. I can't call driver from `@After` and `@Before` methods and all the tests are executed in same browser

Below is the code snippet attached.

```
<bean id="driverProvider" class="com.ecom.utils.DriverProvider" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="webDriver"
      class="org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver"
      factory-bean="driverProvider"
      factory-method="getDriver" scope="prototype"/>


public abstract class BasePage {

    @Autowired
    protected WebDriver driver;


    public void verifyPage() {
        //verify Page
    }

}

@Component
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@id='js-siteMainNavigation']//a[@class='qa-Cl_Menu c-site-nav-main-link-1']")
    private Link MENU_HEADER;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
    }

    public Link getMENU_HEADER() {
        return MENU_HEADER;
    }
}

public class HomePageSteps {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HomePageSteps.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    HomePage homePage;


    @When("I navigate to pizza selection page")
    public void navigateToMenuPage() {
        homePage.getMENU_HEADER().click();
    }

}
```

I don't see a way in calling spring bean from `@After` and `@Before` annotations.
I want to initiate a fresh browser for every feature.

I thought to create Web Driver in Steps and Pass across the Pages, but for this I have to define a constructor with WebDrviver

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
    }
```

But Spring is complain for a bean associated to this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using Spring to inject the browser? Spring will make certain that the same instance, i.e. same browser, is used everywhere. That was dependency injection frameworks do.

Use Spring to inject objects that allows you to share state between steps if the steps are used in different step definition classes.